# Do I need to declare class variables twice?

Tags: python, class, variables, python-2.7

I have been working on something that uses several classes. Right now, my code looks something like this:

```
class name:
  *docstrings and stuff*
  var1=default_value1
  var2=default_value2
  def __init__(self):
    self.var1=default_value1
    self.var2=default_value2
```

I suppose this is not necessary and that I can get away with using only one of the declaration 'blocks', but I don't exactly understand how it works. The variables defined in the class are applied by default when creating a new object? If so, what is exactly the advantage of doing this instead of declaring everything in the constructor?

I'm not exactly sure why I do this, I must've picked it up from some example I saw online (and copypaste did the rest). I was reviewing my code and I want to make sure it makes sense.

Comment: If the variable is a class variable (as opposed to an instance variable) you shouldn't need to define it inside `__init__`. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish in this case, so it's hard to say EXACTLY how best to structure your code. If you post an example class it would be easier to help you.

Comment: "The variables defined in the class are applied by default when creating a new object?" - they're not. They're class variables. If individual instances are expected to have their own values for it, it doesn't belong at class level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user2357112 pointed out, the class variables are not defaults for class instances as I imagined, so defining variables in the class level will not generate those variables and default them to the said value during the construction of an object of that class. Therefore, the variable statements before the constructor are not necessary at all.

I don't exactly know where this misconception came from, but that's exactly what I needed to know. Always double check when reading online tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is a class variable (as opposed to an instance variable) you shouldn't need to define it inside `__init__`. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish in this case, so it's hard to say EXACTLY how best to structure your code.

As an example, I wrote a small module for my company to help me write scripts that access various machines. I work for a retailer, so we generally have two "types" of systems: "Back Office" computers, and "Register" computers.

```
class Machine(object):
    def __init__(self,store):
        self.store = store

class Register(Machine):
    type_ = "Register"
    def __init__(self,store,reg_num):
        super().__init__(self,store)
        self.number = reg_num
        self.IP = # IP address based on store and register number

class BackOffice(Machine)
    type_ = "Back Office"
    def __init__(self,store):
        super().__init__(self,store)
        self.IP = # IP address based on store
```

the `type_` variable is a class variable. `BackOffice("1")` may refer to the back office computer at store #1, and `BackOffice("1").type_ == "Back Office"`. However the `IP` will differ from `BackOffice` to `BackOffice`, so I don't declare that as a class variable but an instance variable.

This might help if I wanted to write a utility that returned all the registers for a list of stores:

```
def listRegisters(storelist):
    stores = makestorelist(storelist) # a separate function that builds
                                      # stores and all their devices
    return [machine for store in stores for 
           machine in store.devices if machine.type_ == "Register]
```

Of course I could also do `if isinstance(machine, Register)` but that's beside the point.